Работа с таблицей Treeview в tkinter
Изучая все возможности tkinter столкнулся с двумя такими вопросами:
1.) Допустим есть абсолютно рандомная таблица, которую мы выводим в окно нашего приложения при помощи ttk.Treeview. Как в данной таблице сделать возможность выделения каждой ячейки и копирования информации из нее при помощи Cntrl+C? Пробовал использовать selectmode, но он выделяет всю строку целиком, а не конкретную ячейку.
2.) Есть ли какая-то возможность задавать длину для каждой ячейки отдельно? Например: заголовки ячеек передаются списком и соответственно на условно какое-то id выделять большую длину не разумно, а на длинное название было бы актуально. Возможно даже использовать длину в зависимости от длины содержимого или самого длинного элемента в конкретном столбце.
Заранее благодарю за помощь, без примера потому что вопросы назрели в моменте изучения модуля, а не конкретного проекта.

1 - сделать, чтобы выделялась не вся строка целиком, нельзя. Копирование отдельной ячейки в целом можно реализовать, см. код тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63194205/4752653. Еще, посмотрите этот контрол таблицы, возможно он вам лучше подойдет: https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet.

Спасибо, полезная информация, буду изучать


Копирование содержимого ячейки в буфер возможно, потому что есть возможность получить содержимое ячейки программно. Я пользуюсь таким получением данных именно из ячейки. Если потребуется, что-то тут допишу по этому поводу.

Есть ли какая-то возможность задавать длину для каждой ячейки отдельно? - это не Excel. Идеология этого виджета - табличная, то есть строки и колонки, или древо. Объект очень примитивный, особенно по сравнению с аналогами в других языках. Настолько, что актуальным становится изучение чего-то более умного, типа PyQt, именно из-за убогости именно этого объекта.
Управление содержимым колонки осуществляется примерно так:
mytreeview.column("column1", anchor = "w", stretch = False, minwidth = 110, width = 110)


где:
column1 - название колонки;
anchor - выравнивание содержимого колонки;
stretch - автоматическая подгонка ширины колонки под содержимое;
minwidth - минимально разрешённая ширина колонки (при изменении размеров, меньше этого значения сделать нельзя);
width - ширина колонки.

Ваш вопрос более всего относится к stretch. Иногда это удобно. Но если содержимое таблицы заведомо не помещается по ширине, такая опция превращает попытку прокрутки в кошмар. Я долго пытался как-то приспособить эту опцию, в результате отказался вообще. У меня всегда False.

Понял, благодарю за объяснение, тоже попробовал на примерах Stretch и не всегда дает тот результат, который бы хотелось)
